# FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Tags: permissions, storage

FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
Anyone have an idea of ​​this error ??

Answer (score -1):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to your **AndroidManifest.xml**